# Timer overlaps react native

Tags: react-native

I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently facing an intriguing challenge with a timer in my React Native screen. Strangely, the timer seems to be running at a faster pace than intended, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause.

Here are some key details about the issue:

The timer logic appears to be correct, with intervals set to 1000 milliseconds (1 second).
I've ensured there are no nested timers that might be causing interference.
The useEffect responsible for the timer cleanup is properly implemented to prevent any lingering timers.
Despite these precautions, the timer continues to accelerate beyond the expected pace. I've reviewed the component for any unnecessary re-renders, checked for asynchronous state updates, and added console logs for debugging, but the issue persists.

If you have any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this mysterious timer acceleration, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Additionally, if you require specific code snippets or more details about the implementation, please let me know.

```
interface TimerScreenProps {
  navigation: any; // Assuming the navigation prop is of any type for simplicity
  
}

interface TimerScreenProps {
  navigation: any; // Assuming the navigation prop is of any type for simplicity
}

const GameScr: React.FC<TimerScreenProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);
  const [modalTime, setModalTime] = useState(3);
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState<any>(null);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
  const [teamsData, setTeamsData] = useState<any>(null);
  const [listCards,setListCard]=useState<string[]>([]);
  const [card,setCard]=useState<string>();
  const [score, setScore] = useState<number>(0);
  const [teamTurn, setTeamTurn] = useState<number>(0);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTeamsData = async () => {
      try {
        const configData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ConfigData');
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(configData);
        setTime(parsedData.seconds);
        const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TeamData');
        console.log('data team: '+storedData);
        const listCardData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('listCards');
        const parsedListCardData = JSON.parse(listCardData);
        const teamt = await AsyncStorage.getItem('teamTurn');
        setListCard(parsedListCardData);
        if (storedData !== null) {
          const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData);
          setTeamsData(parsedData);
        }else{
          console.log('no Data');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchTeamsData();
  }, []);

  const closeModal = useCallback(() => {
    setModalVisible(false);
  }, []);

  const startTimerForTimerScreen = useCallback(() => {
    const timerScreenIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevTime) => {
        if (prevTime === 0) {
          clearInterval(timerScreenIntervalId);
          console.log('TimerScreen Countdown finished');
          // Use navigation.navigate inside useEffect or outside of rendering phase
          requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            navigation.navigate('ScoreScr');
          });
        }
        return prevTime > 0 ? prevTime - 1 : 0;
      });
    }, 1000);
    // Clear existing interval before starting a new one
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerScreenIntervalId);
    };
  }, [navigation]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!modalVisible) {
      startTimerForTimerScreen();
      setCard(listCards[0]);
      listCards.splice(0, 1);
      setListCard(listCards);
    }
  }, [modalVisible, startTimerForTimerScreen, listCards]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!modalVisible) {
      startTimerForTimerScreen();
    }
  }, [modalVisible, startTimerForTimerScreen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!modalVisible) {
      startTimerForTimerScreen();
    }
  }, [modalVisible, startTimerForTimerScreen]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (modalVisible) {
      const modalIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setModalTime((prevTime) => {
          if (prevTime === 0) {
            clearInterval(modalIntervalId);
            console.log('Modal Countdown finished');
            setModalVisible(false);
          }
          return prevTime > 0 ? prevTime - 1 : 0;
        });
      }, 1000);
  
      return () => {
        clearInterval(modalIntervalId);
      };
    }
  }, [modalVisible]);

  const handleTouchable1Press = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * listCards.length);
    const randomElement = listCards[randomIndex];
    setCard(randomElement);
    setScore(score+1);
    if (Array.isArray(listCards) && listCards.length > 0) {
      // Remove the first element from the array
      listCards.splice(randomIndex, 1);
      // Update the state with the modified array
      setListCard(listCards);
    }else{
      setCard('no more cards');
    }
    console.log('Touchable panel 1 pressed'+score);
  };

  const handleTouchable2Press = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * listCards.length);
    const randomElement = listCards[randomIndex];
    setCard(randomElement);
    if (Array.isArray(listCards) && listCards.length > 0) {
      // Remove the first element from the array
      listCards.splice(randomIndex, 1);
      // Update the state with the modified array
      setListCard(listCards);
    }else{
      setCard('no more cards');
    }
    console.log('Touchable panel 2 pressed');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Modal */}
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.modalText}>{modalTime} seconds</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      {/* Timer Layer */}
      <View style={styles.timerLayer}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.timerText}>{time} seconds</Text>
            <View>
              <Text>Card:</Text>
              <Text>{card}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      {/* TouchableOpacity Layer */}
      <View style={styles.touchableOpacityLayer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.touchablePanel}
          onPress={handleTouchable1Press}
          activeOpacity={0} // Set activeOpacity to 0 to make it completely invisible
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.touchablePanel}
          onPress={handleTouchable2Press}
          activeOpacity={0} // Set activeOpacity to 0 to make it completely invisible
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', // Semi-transparent background
  },
  modalText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
  },
  timerLayer: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 1, // Higher zIndex to appear in the back
  },
  touchableOpacityLayer: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 2, // Lower zIndex to appear in the front
    flexDirection: 'row', // Stack TouchableOpacity elements horizontally
  },
  content: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  timerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  touchablePanel: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default GameScr;
```

I appreciate any help

solve the timer problem, to work like any timer with a normal speed